# Canonical Cover & candidate keys for Functional Dependencies

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I'm learning DBMS and am having all sorts of problems understanding how to compute a canonical cover and candidate keys for this relationship

**R=(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)**

**FD's :** X= {AB->C, BC->A, AC->B, E->FG, F->EG, G->EG, H->A}

1.candidate keys: **DHEC, DHFC, DHGC, DHEB, DHFB, DHGB.**

2.canonical cover :**{AB->C, BC->A, AC->B,E->F,F->G,G->E,H->A}**

do you think it's right?

I'm not sure about my canonical cover? can i reduce more FD's?
I thought maybe i can reduce more from these FD's
AB->C, BC->A, AC->B but can't find what of them.

Comment: The candidate keys and the canonical cover are correct. You cannot reduce the dependencies that you have obtained.

Comment: thanks. that's what I thought before, just to be sure.

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, ask a new question. Don't overwrite an old one.